# Take data from firebase to struct

Tags: swift, database, xcode

I created simple database in firebase, and I try take this data to my custom struct. This is my code:

```
 func parseData() -> Array<Dish> {
    var dishes: Array<Dish> = []
    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("dishes")
    reference.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let objects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for item in objects{
                let dish = Dish(snapshot: item)
                dishes.append(dish)
            }
        }
        there all works
        print(dishes[0])
    }
    //out of clousures
    print(dishes[0]) 
    // Error index out of range

    return dishes
}
```

When i returned dishes array she is empty.
My question is how i can used this dishes array out of clousures and return completed array.

Answer (score 0):

You need a completion

```
func parseData(completion:@escaping ( [Dish] -> ()))  {
    var dishes: Array<Dish> = []
    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("dishes")
    reference.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let objects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for item in objects {
                let dish = Dish(snapshot: item)
                dishes.append(dish)
            }
            completion(dishes)
        } 
    } 
}
```

Also think of `observeSingleEvent` instead of `observe` , to call

```
parseData { arr in
  print(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I must initialize properties, arrayDish in other class:

I have somethink like that

```
 func takeData() {
    TakeDataToMainView().parseData { (result) in
        self.arrayDish = result
        self.mainDishCollection.reloadData()
    }
}
```

this is works, but maybe is better way to do this, where i dont need use reloadData?